# ModelBinding enum values for selectlist and selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, enums, query-string, selectlist, model-binding

Ok, this was supposed to be a question asking for help getting my form to work properly. In the process of creating an example to post, I figured out what the fix is.

So now it's a become a question about why it works one way and not the other. I really cannot understand the behaviour. Have I found a bug in MVC? Or is there something I don't understand about html requests which makes this behaviour correct?

The example invloves setting the selected value in a dropdown through an enum property in a view model which is bound from the querystring (it's probaly clearer what I'm talking about if you just read the code):

**Controller/Model**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}

public class TestModel
{
    public SelectList EnumOptions { get; set; }
    public TestEnum EnumValue { get; set; }

    public TestModel()
    {
        var options =  from Enum e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestEnum))
                         select new { Value = e, Name = e.ToString() };

        EnumOptions = new SelectList(options, "Value", "Name", TestEnum.NotSet);
    }
}

public enum TestEnum
{
    NotSet = 0,
    Dog = 1,
    Cat = 2
}
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EnumValue, Model.EnumOptions)

<a href="?EnumValue=Dog">Dog numeric</a>
<a href="?EnumValue=1">Dog string</a>
```

It's all pretty simple.

The question is, why doesn't the second "Dog" link work properly? Note it submits the enumValue as a numeric property, instead of as a "string" property.

But the model binder has no problem with this. **The model supplied to the View is exactly the same in either case**. So how does the dropdown selected value get rendered correctly in one case but not the other?

Answer (score 0):

DropDownListFor looks into the modelstatedictionary for getting the current value of the field/property.
The ValueProviderResult for the second link has a value from 1.

The modelbinder knows that the requested type is a TestEnum. A 1 can be converted to Dog. 
The dropwdownlist converts the value of the ValueProviderResult into a string. A 1 converts to "1" as a string. There is no entry in the selectlist with a value of "1".

Therefor the dropdownlist has a wrong current value.